# xdotool help maximizing

Tags: linux, xdotool

i'm working on setting up an igel device that auto launches a program upon startup. that part works fine. but when it comes up it's not always coming up maximized/full screen.

at first i tried the wmctrl scripts but it doesn't work with the citrix page it's trying to open.

so i switched over to xdotool windowmove and xdotool windowsize. the problem is that it wants to use the windowsID number but that number changes after our daily scheduled reboots.

i think there is a way to do something like:

xdotool windowmove $(xdotool getactivewindow) 0, 0
xdotool windowsize $(xdotool getactivewindow) 100%, 100%

but i can't get the script to delay enough for the window to be open before it runs

granted i'm not very experienced with scripting so i'm hoping it's something easily obtainable?

Answer (score 0):

I would let `xdotool` search for the window rather than try and code in numbers. Once it finds it, it puts the ID in an internal stack. The %@ gets you the last value from this stack.

```
xdotool search --name PROGNAME windowsize %@ 100% 100%
```

for example.

Typically I would use the `class` rather than the name, and I would use `xprop` to find the name to use.

However you might be approaching the problem from the wrong point of view. Almost all X programs will accept a `-geometry` command line flag to specify where they should appear on the screen and their size - although the window manager (if any) can promptly move it. If you can alter the launch script you can probably set the requested size and location.